# combobox column error?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have combobox column in gridview take datasource from

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                                         comboBoxCell.ReadOnly = false;
                                         comboBoxCell.DataSource = itemDetails;
                                         comboBoxCell.DisplayMember = "UnitNameArabic";
                                         comboBoxCell.ValueMember = "UnitID";
                                         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2] = comboBoxCell;
```

i make event `CellValueChanged` to get another data depend on combobox selected value 
i get error in picture then combobox working well 
why i get this error ?

[image]

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {

           for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount-1 ; i++)
            {

                {

                    List<ComboUnit> ItemUnitsList = new List<ComboUnit>();
                    ComboUnit ItemUnitsObj = new ComboUnit();


                    string itemnumber = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                    long SelectedVal = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

                    TechTouch.Methods o = new TechTouch.Methods();
                    List<db.Vitems> itemDetails = o.SearchItem(itemnumber, "29");
                    itemDetails = itemDetails.GroupBy(Pp => Pp.UnitId).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();


                    foreach (var item in itemDetails)
                    {
                        if (item.UnitId == SelectedVal)
                        {

                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToDouble(item.SalePrice);
                            double w = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                            double a = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                            double b = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = Convert.ToDouble(((w * a)));
                        }
                    }

                }


            };


       }
```

Comment: check whether your main method has [STAThread] attribute

Comment: Search for this `static void Main(string[] args)` method and see whether the attribute is present above the method

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that you have the **[STAThread]** attribute above your `main`.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

For more information regarding STAThread and why do you need it, refer to [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/04/07/406341.aspx).

Comment: i have and not working 
`namespace TechTouch_Point
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1  ());
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @KOKO what's in `CellValueChanged ` ? Post code in your main thread and not in comments.